# What does 1<&- & mean?

Tags: bash, unix, jetty

I've got the syntax in /etc/init.d/jetty

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    ...

java -jar start.jar jetty.port=80 1<&- &
```

Can you please explain the redirection at the end of the command?

(By the way my Jetty server stops responding to URL requests in approximately a day.  I can see it is still executing the WAR file since it has a job that runs every 5 minutes, but the web server is not responding to URL requests as far as I can tell using the Chrome developer tools.  So I'm trying to see Jetty's log)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually two separate commands. First:

```
1<&-
```

This closes stdout, from the [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> The redirection operator
>
> [n]<&word
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors. If word expands to one or
>   more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of
>   that file descriptor. If the digits in word do not specify a file
>   descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs. If word
>   evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n is closed. If n is not specified,
>   the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

The second ampersand is not a redirection, it's a job control command which tells the shell to run the entire `java` command in the background.

Comment: I thought < related to input, not output?

Comment: You can think of it as saying "the input to stdout is now nothing"

Comment: @Ray, `<` is an input to whatever is to the left of it. In this case, the file descriptor for `stdout` is on the left. Refer to Josh's comment.